# How to add the controller name in logstash-logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logstash

I'm using [Logstash-logger](https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger). I would like to know how to add the controller name or routes to appears automatically in the logs. Here is the default logs

```
      #production.log  
{
        "message":"  Couldn't find template for digesting: docs/#{@doc.layout}",
        "@timestamp":"2015-10-28T22:15:05.963+00:00",
        "@version":"1",
        "severity":"ERROR",
        "host":"localhost"
       }
```

expected

```
{
        "message":"  Couldn't find template for digesting: docs/#{@doc.layout}",
        "@timestamp":"2015-10-28T22:15:05.963+00:00",
        "@version":"1",
        "severity":"ERROR",
        "host":"localhost",
        "routes" : "AticlesController#index",
        #or from view
        "view": "Articles#index#_partial_name
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Author of LogStashLogger here. I would recommend that you check out the [Logstasher](https://github.com/shadabahmed/logstasher) or [Lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) gems. They both have very good support for logging information about the controller and views involved in the request.